# Codeigniter - Internal Server Error 500 when adding to database via AJAX & jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am having issues adding a chunk of content to my database, the content is in a WYSIWYG editor and what i want to happen is for the save button to be clicked, and the content is passed through the jquery/ajax function to the controller and saved to my database for later use..

the table in my database is Templates with Template style where i want to store the content, an auto incremented primary key, and Userstempid which is the current logged in users foreign key id to the template

when i click the save button I am getting an internal server error 500 in the console, any help at all would be massively appreciated

I am new to codeigniter so i am not quite sure whether there is a problem with my querys etc or something different

**My View - wysiwyg editor is trumbowyg-demo & jquery ajax**

```
<h5> Design Your Email </h5>
            <p>Use the editor below to design and fill in your email's content</p>
          <div id="trumbowyg-demo"></div>
          <h2 class="center light-blue-text">

 <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light center-align" type="submit" id="saveContent">Save Current Content
                      <i class="material-icons right">note_add</i>
   </button>



    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#saveContent").click(function () {
          var content = $("#trumbowyg-demo").html();
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/Dashboard/add",
              data: {
                  content: content
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (data) {
                  if (data.status == 'error') {
                      alert('An error occured: ' + data.msg);
                  } else {
                      alert(data.msg)
                  }
              }
          });
      });
```

**My Controller - Dashboard.php**

```
        public function add(){

    $this->load->model('template_model');
        $this->template_model->AddTemplate();

         }
```

**My Model - Template_model.php**

```
    class Template_model extends CI_Model {


      Public function AddTemplate(){
        $content = $this->input->post('templatestyle');,
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('users_temp_id');
         $this->db->insert('templates', array('templatestyle' =>$content, 'users_temp_id'=>$user_id));
    }
```

Comment: please don't use code snippet to (only) format your code, it's meant to create a working example!

Comment: Could you paste in the error you're getting back?

Comment: @opticon i am getting 'POST https://myapp.com/Dashboard/add 500 (Internal Server Error)' in the console

Comment: try this https://pastebin.com/L6kfCuX3

Comment: @plonknimbuzz no still getting the same error and not adding to the database

Comment: try change dashboard.php to `public function add(){
 $this->db->insert('templates', array('templatestyle' =>'aaaa', 'users_temp_id'=>1));echo $this->db->affected_rows();
}` then access `directly to yourCiURL/dashboard/add` what the return of that

Comment: okay, you are on to something now.. this returns @plonknimbuzz

Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`b00664112`.`templates`, CONSTRAINT `users_temp_id` FOREIGN KEY (`users_temp_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))

INSERT INTO `templates` (`templatestyle`, `users_temp_id`) VALUES ('aaaa', 1)

Comment: from my script above, change `users_temp_id` with valid user_temp_id from your db which i dont know. then run it again

Comment: @plonknimbuzz okay that added to the database, so im almost there, cant think of what the problem is then

Comment: Also the post variable isn't called templatestyle it's called content. This will yield nothing.

Comment: You have to make sure a user with that Id exists in the user table

Comment: Try to change the file name first letter capital of model file i.e `$this->template_model->AddTemplate();`  to     `$this->Template_model->AddTemplate();` .This will help you

Answer (score 0):

Always create the array(insert_data) first and pass it as a parameter

```
// your are sending 'content' not 'templatestyle' in ajax request
$content = $this->input->post('templatestyle');

// use this
$content = $this->input->post('content');
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('users_temp_id');
$insert_data = array(
                    'templatestyle'     => $content,
                    'users_temp_id' => $user_id,
                  );
$this->db->insert('templates',$insert_data);
```